# Stop Mesh render on intersect

Tags: unity, c#

I am generating camera frustum mesh through code, it is working fine. Now I am searching a solution (shader based or else) to restrict
the camera frustum mesh if it intersect with any object. Like you can see in the image my frustum is passing through the plane which is not correct.
How can I control it, I search and apply different kind of shader but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: Can you set the end point/distance/length of the frustum mesh? If so then why can't you use raycast to find the distance or coordinate to use with frustum mesh code?

Comment: each mesh of the frustum consist of single triangle. a single triangle can hit to multiple objects at differe times. so how can i limit it through mesh.?

Comment: I am not so familiar with this as well, I just had an idea from how I understood it

Comment: each frustum mesh consist of a single triangle and there are 4 triangle. left right top bottom who representing the camera frustum.

Comment: Couldn't you just go to your Draw-Function and test the position of the vertices to be inside of your Frustum? And only render them if they are? But I don't know, whether this is possible in Unity or not.